# Number of facet values

Tags: algolia

I'm investigating Algolia as a search technology for an application that will have a large number of facet values for one of the fields that will be faceted on (i.e. ~4000).

Does anyone know if there is there a practical limit to the number of facet values that are supported (i.e. will ~4000 have significant performance implications as we scale)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you mean by scaling.
But as a matter of reference, you can imagine that [Medium](https://medium.com/search?q=test), which is using Algolia, has, I guess, millions of articles and tens of thousands of tags and has no performance issue.

If your use-case grows a lot and you start having [Enterprise plan](https://www.algolia.com/pricing) needs, you'll have people to talk to directly at Algolia to think with you about those performance implications.

If you're not convinced and are on trial, you should have no issues pushing some fake data to see if everything works as expected!